# Error N + 1 utilizando paquete Caffeinated Shinobi

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando el paquete de Shinobi para los permisos de mi aplicación. Las estoy utilizando con la directiva @can para mostrar opciones dependiendo del rol del usuario.

A simple vista funciona bien, pero al revisar las peticiones a la base de datos veo que se hacen 85 peticiones solo para los permisos.

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que forma puedo precargar todos los roles para evitar este error?

Esta es la parte donde el paquete obtiene los permisos:

```
protected function getPermissions(array $collection)
{
    return array_map(function($permission) {
        $model = $this->getPermissionModel();

        if ($permission instanceof Permission) {
            return $permission->id;
        }

        $permission = $model->where('slug', $permission)->first();

        return $permission->id;
    }, $collection);
}
```

En esta parte el paquete obtiene los roles:

```
public function hasRole($role): bool
{
    $slug = Str::slug($role);

    return (bool) $this->roles->where('slug', $slug)->count();
}
```

Estas son las dos consultas que se ejecutan al cargar cada uno de los permisos de un usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestranos la consulta que genera el problema

Comment: @BetaM acabo de agregar las partes en donde veo que el paquete hace las consultas.

Comment: Ok y cuál de las dos es?

Comment: @BetaM son ambas, acabo de agregar las dos consultas que se repiten por cada uno de los registros.